# Passing Collections Immutably

Tags: c#

I'm doing a big refactor of a pile of code that used to use a bunch of multidimensional arrays that were constantly getting resized. I created a data object to replace the 2D array, and I'm now passing a list of these around.

I discovered something that worries me a little though. Let's say I have some code that looks like this:

```
List<NCPoint> basePoints = new List<NCPoint>();

// ... snip populating basePoints with starting data

List<NCPoint> newPoints = TransformPoints(basePoints, 1, 2, 3);

public List<NCPoint> TransformPoints(List<NCPoint> points, int foo, int bar, int baz){
    foreach(NCPoint p in points){
        points.X += foo
        points.Y += bar
        points.Z += baz
    }

    return points;
}
```

The idea is to keep a list of the original points (`basePoints`) and a list of the updated points (`newPoints`). But C# passes the list by reference, as with any object. This updates `basePoints` in place, so now both `basePoints` and `newPoints` will have the same data.

At the moment, I'm trying to be careful about making a full copy of the passed-in `List` before I muck with the data. Is that the only sensible way to make sure changes to an object within a function don't have side effects outside the function? Is there anything akin to passing an object with `const`?

Comment: At some point, if you want to have a new, different, collection, and still have the old one as is, a copy of the list items will need to take place.  You might be able to get someone else to do that copy, but somewhere it'll be happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: no.

C# does not have the concept of a `const` reference, per se.  If you want to make an object immutable, you must code it explicitly so or take advantage of other "tricks".

You can make your collection immutable in many ways (`ReadOnlyColelction`, return an iterator, return a shallow copy) but that *only* protects the sequence, not the data stored inside.

Thus, what you'd really need to do what you want is to return a deep copy or projection, possibly using LINQ:

```
public IEnumerable<NCPoint> TransformPoints(List<NCPoint> points, int foo, int bar, int baz)
{
    // returning an iterator over the sequence so original list won't be changed
    // and creating new NCPoint using old NCPoint + modifications so old points
    // aren't altered.
    return points.Select(p => new NCPoint
        { 
           X = p.X + foo,
           Y = p.Y + bar,
           Z = p.Z + baz
        });
}
```

Also, the beauty of returning an iterator (as opposed to just returning a `List<T>` as an `IEnumerable<T>`, etc.) is that it can't be cast back to the original collection type.

**UPDATE**: Or, in .NET 2.0 parlance:

```
public IEnumerable<NCPoint> TransformPoints(List<NCPoint> points, int foo, int bar, int baz)
{
    // returning an iterator over the sequence so original list won't be changed
    // and creating new NCPoint using old NCPoint + modifications so old points
    // aren't altered.
    NCPoint[] result = new NCPoint[points.Count];

    for (int i=0; i<points.Count; ++i)
    { 
        // if you have a "copy constructor", can use it here.
        result[i] = new NCPoint();
        result[i].X = points[i].X + foo;
        result[i].Y = points[i].Y + bar;
        result[i].Z = points[i].Z + baz;
    }

    return result;
}
```

The point is, there are many ways to treat something as immutable, but I wouldn't try to implement C++-style "const correctness" in C# or you will go mad.  Implement it as needed when you want to avoid side-effects, etc.

Comment: I kind of feared that this was the case. Glad to get confirmation at least. Unfortunately I'm stuck in .NET 2.0 so no fancy LINQ for me =(. Foreach loop should do it though. The `NCPoint` object has a deep copy constructor.

Comment: @KChaloux: Ah, in any case the same principles apply, return a new `List<T>` then with your deep copies and then modify the copies.

Answer (score 3):

You probabbly searching for  [ReadOnlyCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx)

> Provides the base class for a generic read-only collection.

Example:

```
public IEnumerable<..> GetReadonlyCollection(List<...> originalList) 
{
  return new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(originalList);
}
```

Just invite attention on one fact: that this is provides service for making readonly (immutable) *a collection* and *not* containing type. I can get an object frim that collection and change it, and if the object is reference type, those changes would have their reflection in the original collection too.

If you want to have readonly *object*, this becomes a little bit more tricky (depends how complex your object is). The basic idea is (suggested by Servy too) is making a *wrapper* over your original object with *readonly* public members (so for consumer of *that* type it becomes immutable).

Hope this helps.

Comment: He wants to modify the objects, but have them return copies, ReadOnlyCollection won't let him do that, it only protects the list itself.

Comment: The underlying principle here, which can be apply to making an immutable wrapper over any mutable variable, is to have either a wrapper class or an interface with a limited subset of the provided functionality (i.e. read but no write).

Comment: +1 For the clarification on not providing immutability on the enclosed type. I was doing a test with it and felt a little confused when I was still able to edit the properties of the contents.

Comment: It looks like I can't quite do what I want short of making an explicit copy of the list that's safe to mutate. This was still a helpful answer, if not ultimately directly applicable.

Comment: @KChaloux: you can create a wrapper object, if not making a clone is a solution too, sure.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C# 4.5 I would recomend taking a look at Immutable Collections, which can be downloaded through Nuget package...

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Bcl.Immutable
```

this blog post explains very well how to use them:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/09/25/immutable-collections-ready-for-prime-time.aspx

To protect the enclosed object, you have to make all properties private.
I Like the `.With..(..)`  pattern to help building objects

```
    public class NCPoint
    {
        public int X { get; private set; }
        public int Y { get; private set; }
        public int Z { get; private set; }

        public NCPoint(int x, int y, int z)
        {
            this.X = x;
            this.Y = y;
            this.Z = z;
        }

        public NCPoint WithX (int x)
        {
            return x == X ? this : new NCPoint(x, Y, Z);
        }

        public NCPoint WithY(int y)
        {
            return y == Y ? this : new NCPoint(X, y, Z);
        }

        public NCPoint WithZ(int z)
        {
            return z == Z ? this : new NCPoint(X, Y, z);
        }
    }
```

You can use it like this:

```
var p = points[i];
var newPoint = p.WithX(p.X + foo)
                .WithY(p.Y + bar)
                .WithZ(p.Z + baz);
```

I understand this solution is not appreciated by everybody, since it requires a lot of coding. But I find it quite elegant.

In the end, call the Replace Method of the Immutable List:

`immutablePoints.Replace (p, newPoint);`